# Undefined problems in my website Codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a website ( https://wtf.az/ ), but when I want to change the language it refreshes the page but does not change on the first attempt. However, when I click on another URL it changes the language. Also, this problem occurs when I want to log in. Where can be the problem? Here is the controller:

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class LanguageSwitcher extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();     
    }

    function switchLang($language = "") {

        $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "azerbaijani";
        $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);

        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    }
}
```

Here is my hook:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class LanguageLoader
{
    function initialize() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->load->helper('language');
        $siteLang = $ci->session->userdata('site_lang');
        if ($siteLang) {
            $ci->lang->load('header',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('footer',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('index',$siteLang);

        } else {
            $ci->lang->load('header','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('footer','azerbaijani');
            $ci->lang->load('index','azerbaijani');

        }
    }
}
```

I have changed `$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;` to `$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/';` . Can it cause this problem?

[image]

Comment: did you check it in the controller constructor ? try to initialize the language in the constructor

Comment: how should I check it?

Comment: Setting up language preference with sessions is the wrong way to handle i18n.

Comment: what way do you prefer?

Comment: @JavidAbbasov is it fixed or still have problem ?

Comment: @AbidNawaz I still have problem

Comment: @JavidAbbasov may be this  redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); causing the problem.  use redirect(base_url());  also include this $this->load->helper('url'); line to constructor

Comment: @JavidAbbasov problem fixed ?

Comment: @AbidNawaz yes it is

Comment: Tip You have named your classes wrong for codeigniter explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

to

`redirect(base_url());`

and add `$this->load->helper('url');` to the Constructor.

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Languageswitcher extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
    }

    function switchLang($language = "") {

        $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "azerbaijani";
        $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);

        redirect(base_url());

    }
}
```